# Windows Azure SQL Database Connection String Does Not Work When Solution Deployed

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an MVC3 solution (EF 5/Net 4.5) that is connecting to a SQL Azure database.  When I run the solution locally, it’s configured to connect up to the SQL Azure database, the solution works fine.  However, when I publish the solution to Azure the connection to the SQL Azure database does not work.

It’s the same connection string in both the ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.csfg and ServiceConfiguration.Local.csfg files.  I’ve also made sure that through the Azure portal the server that the Azure SQL DB is running on has “Windows Azure Services” as “Allowed Services” set to “Yes”
The connection string is:

```
<Setting name="SQLDataConnectionString" value="metadata=res://*/FooDB.csdl|res://*/FooDB.ssdl|res://*/FooDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:sahjjh7.database.windows.net,1433;Database=FooDB;User ID=<real user id>;Password=<real password>;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;&quot;" />
```

Any pointers?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Entity Framework knows how to grab connection strings from the ServiceConfiguration. Did you point it there yourself? If not, it could actually be an issue with a web.config transform.